How can i start conductor standalone without docker
starting conductor-server standalone with elastic-search and redis
i tried multiple versions of conductor sever, it is connecting to redis but unable to connect elastic search, after creating and running workflow it is not visible in executions tab.

Here i am going to provide answer step by step(on linux platform)
Requirements:

java(jdk) 17
gradle 8.5
elasticsearch-7.17.25
redis(latest version)
node v14.17.3


clone repository


git clone https://github.com/Netflix/conductor.git


go to conductor/server directory


cd conductor/server


open build.gradle file and comment below line and save file

bootJar {
mainClass = 'com.netflix.conductor.Conductor'
//classifier = 'boot'  // comment only this line

}

go to conductor/server/src/main/resources directory and open  application.properties file and edit the follwing propertis apart from this do not change anything

conductor.db.type=redis_standalone
conductor.queue.type=redis_standalone
conductor.indexing.enabled=true


come back to conductor/server directory



gradle clean


gradle build -x test


check your installed elastic-search by using following curl command in terminal


curl http://localhost:9200

it will show like this:
{
"name" : "localhost.localdomain",
"cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
"cluster_uuid" : "iSCIKWH6SC23CCZHZG_TuA",
"version" : {
"number" : "7.17.25",
"build_flavor" : "default",
"build_type" : "rpm",
"build_hash" : "f9b6b57d1d0f76e2d14291c04fb50abeb642cfbf",
"build_date" : "2024-10-16T22:06:36.904732810Z",
"build_snapshot" : false,
"lucene_version" : "8.11.3",
"minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
"minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
},
"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

check your installed redis by using following curl command in terminal, it should listen to default port 6379
go to /etc/redis directory


redis-cli


ping


now go to conductor/server/build/libs directory


java -jar conductor-server-3.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

conductor-server should start on default port 8080

go to conductor/ui  directory and run following command


npm install

once it adds node-modules, run next command

npm start


run following url in any browser


http://ip:port

eg.  http://127.0.0.1:5000
everything is done and you are ready to create your workflow
